# Get input from voice

Tags: python, reactjs, chatbot, voice-recognition

I'm working on a chatbot project. I've created a speech recognition using python. For example if I say "Hi" it will return the input as `"Hi"` in text. If I give `"Hi"` as a text it will say "Hi". I've done this by `text to speech`, and `speech to text` function (I checked on the command line).

But My front-end is ReactJs. If the user press the microphone button it has to start to listen then it should give the output as voice.

So now I have the function to change the voice to text as well as text to voice. But how can I get it from ReactJs?

Comment: So do you want to run python on the server and reactjs on client side on the browser? Why do you need python then if you can do everything in the browser itself.

Comment: Well, if it can be done on the browser. How can I do it?

Comment: Like this https://www.twilio.com/blog/speech-recognition-browser-web-speech-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find answer [here](http://L%20=%20[%22Geeks%5Cn%22,%20%22for%5Cn%22,%20%22Geeks%5Cn%22]%20%20%20%20%20#%20writing%20to%20file%20%20file1%20=%20open('myfile.txt',%20'w')%20%20file1.writelines(L)%20%20file1.close()%20%20%20%20%20#%20Using%20readlines()%20%20file1%20=%20open('myfile.txt',%20'r')%20%20Lines%20=%20file1.readlines()%20%20%20%20%20count%20=%200%20#%20Strips%20the%20newline%20character%20%20for%20line%20in%20Lines:%20%20%20%20%20%20print(%22Line%7B%7D:%20%7B%7D%22.format(count,%20line.strip())))

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/speech-recognition-browser-web-speech-api this is the link